# Export json encrypted with spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

on my system 
People's data should be exported to a Rest-based system via json, the post body payload should be encrypted ... as my knowledge are small with rest and springboot I have no idea if I'm doing it right .. ..I think not.
* I'm using jooq

Here I am looking for people and return a list of people

```
       Result<Record> result = ctx.select()
                .from(PERSON)
                .orderBy(PERSON.NUM)
                .fetch();

        for (Record r : result) {
            Integer lNum = r.getValue(PERSON.NUM);
            String name = r.getValue(PERSON.SNOME);
            String rm = r.getValue(PERSON.SRM);

            personDto = new AlunoDto();
            personDto.setlNum(num);
            personDto.setsNome(name);
            personDto.setsRm(rm);
            personList.add(personDto);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    **return personList;**
```

In my PersonController I get the list of people and step as parameter to the method that converts to json and encrypts

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllPerson(){
    try {
       personsEncypted= convertToJson(personList);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return personsEncypted;
}

   public String  convertToJson(List obj) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String onInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);

    String key = "00000000000000000000000000"; 
    String personEncrypted= encrypt(key, jsonInString);
    return personEncrypted;
}

public static String encrypt(String key, String value) {
    try {

   SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

hitting the address in the browser is how the data appears
[image]

Will the other side consume the data? thank you so much...

Comment: Es una solución bastante interesante, ya que en el navegador cualquiera puede ver los datos que responde el microservicio y suele ocurrir que los datos sensibles no queremos que los puedan interpretar.

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work.

Simple solution is to use TLS(HTTPS). No encryption code needed, just some configuration in your java web server or in some load balancer fronting the server, like apache2 or nginx.

Even if the http client was cooperating, symmetric algorithm like AES would not work. Client would need to know the same secret key.

Comment: Ah yes ... he'll know, I'll do the other part myself ...
we will use the same key,